# Show thumbnail of News Author in Sitefinty

Tags: thumbnails, sitefinity, author, detailview

I have crated 1 news item in Sitefinty news content section .How can i get Image of News  Author in Sitefinty . I have uploaded my pic in my sitefinty profile and crated 1 news Item but no idea i have for display my image on the  news detail page .I am using Sitefinty 6.3.

Answer (score 1):

This will have to be a user control referenced from the news widget details template that looks up the profile that created the news post.

I've got a custom control in my solution at ~/CustomControls/AuthorPicture.ascx, in the ascx file its just a .net image control:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgAuthor" />
```

In the code behind for the control, use this:

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.UI;
            using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
            using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries;
            using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.News;
            using Telerik.Sitefinity.Security;
            using Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Model;

            namespace SitefinityWebApp.CustomControls
            {
                public partial class AuthorPicture : System.Web.UI.UserControl
                {
                    public Guid NewsId { get; set; }

                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (NewsId == Guid.Empty) return;

                        var newsManager = NewsManager.GetManager();

                        var newsItem = newsManager.GetNewsItems().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == NewsId);

                        if (newsItem == null) return;

                        var userManager = UserManager.GetManager();
                        var upManager = UserProfileManager.GetManager();

                        var owner = userManager.GetUser(newsItem.Owner);

                        var profile = upManager.GetUserProfile<SitefinityProfile>(owner);

                        var lmanager = LibrariesManager.GetManager();
                        var image = lmanager.GetImage(profile.Avatar.ChildItemId);

                        imgAuthor.ImageUrl = image.ThumbnailUrl;
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can see that we'll be passing in the news item id through the NewsId Guid property on the control.

To just show how this works, create a page in Sitefinity and add a News widget on to the page. Click "Edit" select "One particular news item" and select your news item. Under the "Single Item Settings" tab select your details template, the default name is "Full News Item". Click "Edit Selected Template" and register your control  in the template:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" TagName="AuthorImage" Src="~/CustomControls/AuthorPicture.ascx" %>
```

Then somewhere in the RadListView itemTemplate, use the control and pass in the news Id to the property:

```
<custom:AuthorImage runat="server" ID="cstmAuthorImage" NewsId='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
```

Save the changes and publish your page, your new control should be run, and it should pull the profile image of whoever created the post.

I found something similar in Sitefinity forums here: http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/retrieving-post-author-details-avatar-nickname-etc-in-blog-post-templates

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a new template for the News detail. Inside here you can attach to the ItemDataBound event where you can set an image for the news item.

The Author field has no relation to a Sitefinity User, so you need to get the ID of the user that created the Newsitem. (the owner)

This code shows you how to do this:

```
protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadListViewItemEventArgs e) {

        var data = ((RadListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem as NewsItem;

        // Get the owner
        var owner = userManager.GetUser(data .Owner);
    }
```

The logic for retrieving a user and an image you can find in the code from Ben.

Another way would be to create a custom field which shows you a UserPicker field, which would then allow you to be completely flexible on choosing which Sitefinity User you will relate to a news item.